# Python3 When to use? What libraries are available?

Tags: python, unicode, network-programming, python-3.x

I am thinking to develop new applications in python3.

The requirements of the applications are:

File IO, JSON, DB , Well support for Unicode , Web(Optional) . Desktop GUI (Optional), indexing and TCP/IP .

so here are the questions :

1. When do you think we will be using python 3 for realworld applications? The site saids """won't be using python3 for years""", that was since 3 years ago.
2. From above needs which opensource libraries are avaliable for python
   3?
3. Is that true that Python2 still outperforms python3 regarding in
   I/O areas?

Comment: Their site has been saying, "You should probably just use python 2" for years. I wonder when 3 is going to become the standard?

Comment: I was waiting for this """for years""" for 3 years already :D.so i want some judgement from someone who is actually using Python3 to develop a RealWorld application.

Comment: I also wonder if python 3 would ever become standard?

Comment: Question 2 and 3 are valid ones. The first question is probably a bad fit for SO: there is no "correct" answer, people can only speculate.

Comment: Python 2.7 is the last major release of the 2.x series. Starting from 3.3 only the 3.x branch will see addition of new features... So it will sometimes become the mainstream one. Some distro (like ArchLinux) already ship with Python3 as default.

Comment: @mac well yeah speculation should be ok as many important libs/framework are still not python3 ready Yet. How can i turn this into community wiki?

Comment: 1. Around half Green 2 and 3 norths. 2. Most of it is built in. Desktop GUI and Web have limited options compared to Python 2, but there are options. 3. No, that was Python 3.0. (But don't  make loads of seeks on text files).

Comment: Briefly: IO, JSON, Unicode are all supported out of the box. DB: there's SQLite built in, I don't know about the interfaces for other DBs. GUIs: PyQt/PySide, Gtk via Gobject introspection, or Tkinter built in. Web: I think CherryPy and Bottle already support Python 3, and someone's working on it for Django. I'm not quite sure what you need for 'Indexing' and 'TCP/IP'.